# Virtual environment in R?

Tags: r, python

I've found several posts about best practice, reproducibility and workflow in R, for example:

- [How to increase longer term reproducibility of research (particularly using R and Sweave)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4466/how-to-increase-longer-term-reproducibility-of-research-particularly-using-r-an)
- [Complete substantive examples of reproducible research using R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/complete-substantive-examples-of-reproducible-research-using-r)

One of the major preoccupations is ensuring portability of code, in the sense that moving it to a new machine (possibly running a different OS) is relatively straightforward and gives the same results.

Coming from a Python background, I'm used to the concept of a virtual environment.  When coupled with a simple list of required packages, this goes some way to ensuring that the installed packages and libraries are available on any machine without too much fuss.  Sure, it's no guarantee - different OSes have their own foibles and peculiarities - but it gets you 95% of the way there.

Does such a thing exist within R?  Even if it's not as sophisticated.  For example simply maintaining a plain text list of required packages and a script that will install any that are missing?

I'm about to start using R in earnest for the first time, probably in conjunction with Sweave, and would ideally like to start in the best way possible!  Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Good question. I voted for migrating this to SO. The question has no statistical content, so the  SO people could probably give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, and good point.  I've requested a migration from the moderators.

Comment: Renv might do what you're looking for: https://github.com/viking/Renv

Comment: Maintaining a list of packages and isolating them from the system library is exactly what packrat does for R: http://rstudio.github.io/packrat/

Comment: Someone should put an answer in a legit answer instead of the comments. I don't know enough R to answer, but from looking at the links, Renv appears to just manage versions of R while Packrat's docs sound more like a match for virtualenv in which you can use the same language version with different dependency sets in different projects.

Comment: "probably in conjunction with Sweave" --- Do yourself a favor and start with `knitr`, not Sweave.

Comment: @Gabriel Please consider accepting a different answer, since the currently accepted one is outdated and misleading. The correct answer nowadays is https://stackoverflow.com/a/60529391/1968.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It looks like there is another option from RStudio devs, [renv](https://blog.rstudio.com/2019/11/06/renv-project-environments-for-r/). It's available on CRAN and supersedes Packrat.

In short, you use `renv::init()` to initialize your project library, and use `renv::snapshot()` / `renv::restore()` to save and load the state of your library.

I prefer this option to conda r-enviroments because here everything is stored in the file `renv.lock`, which can be committed to a Git repo and distributed to the team.

Comment: This answer should definitely be the accepted answer in our time.

Comment: Fair warning, there are quite a few unresolved issues with renv and Bioconductor packages as of 5-26-21 (some of which I experienced first hand). https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues?q=bioconductor . Kind of a deal breaker for me at the moment.

Answer (score 50):

I'm going to use the comment posted by @cboettig in order to resolve this question.

### Packrat

Packrat is a dependency management system for R. Gives you three important advantages (all of them focused in your portability needs)

- Isolated : Installing a new or updated package for one project won’t break your other projects, and vice versa. That’s because packrat gives each project its own private package library.
- Portable: Easily transport your projects from one computer to another, even across different platforms. Packrat makes it easy to install the packages your project depends on.
- Reproducible: Packrat records the exact package versions you depend on, and ensures those exact versions are the ones that get installed wherever you go.

### What's next?

1. Walkthrough guide: http://rstudio.github.io/packrat/walkthrough.html
2. Most common commands: http://rstudio.github.io/packrat/commands.html
3. Using Packrat with RStudio: http://rstudio.github.io/packrat/rstudio.html
4. Limitations and caveats: http://rstudio.github.io/packrat/limitations.html

**Update:** Packrat has been [soft-deprecated](https://github.com/rstudio/packrat#note) and is now superseded by [renv](https://github.com/rstudio/renv), so you might want to check this package instead.

Comment: What would be the Packrat way of capturing your dependencies in a `requirements.txt` file and installing then via `pip install -r ...`?

Comment: I don't know why but packrat is extremely slow to install packages. Literally lost two days for every time I tried to download a new package

Comment: @Nick The docs [here](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/commands.html) show a `snapshot` command for that.

Answer (score 32):

The Anaconda package manager `conda` [supports creating R environments](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/use-r-language).

```
conda create -n r-environment r-essentials r-base
conda activate r-environment
```

I have had a great experience using `conda` to maintain different Python installations, both user specific and several versions for the same user. I have tested R with `conda` and the `jupyter-notebook` and it works great. At least for my needs, which includes RNA-sequencing analyses using the `DEseq2` and related packages, as well as `data.table` and `dplyr`. There are many bioconductor packages available in `conda` via [bioconda](https://bioconda.github.io/) and according to the comments on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705917/conda-how-to-install-r-packages-that-are-not-available-in-r-essentials), it seems like `install.packages()` might work as well.

Comment: I have also moved into bioinformatics now, so your answer becomes even more relevant! What IDE do you use? I've had trouble integrating conda into Rstudio - it doesn't want to use the correct interpreter path.

Comment: Fun! I use the jupyter-notebook for most of my needs. I did use Rstudio previously, but I remember also having some trouble getting it running with conda and I am used to the notebook from python (which is what I use most frequently by far), so that's where I feel the most comfortable.

Comment: My conda R was still showing my non-conda R's library location in `.libPaths()` and trying to install new packages there, I had to run `export R_LIBS_USER="/path/to/miniconda2/envs/r.3.3/lib/R/library"` in the terminal before starting R and trying to install packages. Still testing but it looks like its working.

Answer (score 1):

To add to this:

Note:
1. Have Anaconda installed already
2. Assumed your working directory is "C:"

To create desired environment -> "r_environment_name"

```
C:\>conda create -n "r_environment_name" r-essentials r-base
```

To see available environments

```
C:\>conda info --envs
```

.
..
...

To activate environment

```
C:\>conda activate "r_environment_name"

(r_environment_name) C:\>
```

Launch Jupyter Notebook and let the party begins

```
(r_environment_name) C:\> jupyter notebook
```

For a similar "requirements.txt", perhaps this link will help -> [Is there something like requirements.txt for R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928326/is-there-something-like-requirements-txt-for-r)

Answer (score 0):

Check out roveR, the R container management solution. For details, see https://www.slideshare.net/DavidKunFF/ownr-technical-introduction, in particular slide 12.

To install roveR, execute the following command in R:

```
install.packages("rover", repos = c("https://lair.functionalfinances.com/repos/shared", "https://lair.functionalfinances.com/repos/cran"))
```

To make full use of the power of roveR (including installing specific versions of packages for reproducibility), you will need access to a laiR - for CRAN, you can use our laiR instance at https://lair.ownr.io, for uploading your own packages and sharing them with your organization you will need a laiR license. You can contact us on the email address in the presentation linked above.

Comment: I think this resource no longer exists

Comment: Yeah, the slideshare is gone.  I can't connect to the two repositories in this answer either, nor https://lair.ownr.io/ .

Comment: Sorry guys, laiR is temporarily offline, we are working on integrating it into our other product (the ownR platform) and will make it available again asap.

Comment: content not available, seems that this isn't an answer at the current time

Answer (score 0):

For *.ipynb* files a R kernel is enough, you do NOT need to install a virtual environment with R, just:

- install R kernel: https://irkernel.github.io/installation/#linux-panel
- run `jupyter notebook` in terminal
- select the *.ipynb* in browser and switch in tab "Kernel" / Change kernel / R
  [image]