# How do I detach all objects and methods from a specific package in R?

Tags: r, methods, environment-variables, r-s4

I need to load and detach a lot of packages in one R session (I'm looking at which functions are methods across different packages). `detach()` doesn't work for what I want, because it doesn't remove everything from the environment; for example, if you run:

```
require(pomp)
detach('package:pomp', character.only = TRUE)
print(methods('show'))
```

the `show,pomp.fun-method` is still listed, which is not a method that exists in base R. How do I remove **all** methods and objects associated with a package? Alternately, is there a way to create a temporary environment in R to load the package, which I can then destroy to remove all objects in methods in a package?

Comment: use packrat 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283171/virtual-environment-in-r

Comment: Try `detach('package:pomp', unload = TRUE, character.only = TRUE)`

Comment: Or `devtools::unload(pkg = "pomp")`. The help for `unload` has a little bit of info on why things can be difficult for S4 classes.

Comment: I want to only use base R functions if at all possible, so I'd rather not use `devtools::unload`, but the `unload` option for `detach` seems to be working. @ialm if you submit that as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To try to unload the namespace that was loaded when loading a package, you have to set the argument `unload = TRUE` in `detach()`.

In your example:

```
detach('package:pomp', unload = TRUE, character.only = TRUE)
```

However, if you read the details in the docs (`?detach`), there are some things to watch out for:

> If a package has a namespace, detaching it does not by default unload
>   the namespace (***and may not even with unload = TRUE***), and detaching
>   will not in general unload any dynamically loaded compiled code
>   (DLLs). Further, registered S3 methods from the namespace will not be
>   removed. If you use library on a package whose namespace is loaded, it
>   attaches the exports of the already loaded namespace. So detaching and
>   re-attaching a package may not refresh some or all components of the
>   package, and is inadvisable.

Emphasis mine. Be wary that it may not always work.