# use conda skeleton to build an r bioconductor package

Tags: r, conda

I know that its generally easier to install r packages, even within condas, using [install packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914819/conda-build-r-ldavis-not-working), or similar. But I also know that I can usually build my own package with, for instance

```
conda skeleton cran tensorA
conda build r-tensorA
conda install --use-local r-tensorA
```

But what if the package lives in `bioconda`, rathaer than `cran`? `DECIPHER`, for instance can be installed within R by [running](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DECIPHER.html)

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("DECIPHER")
```

For primarily learning purposes, I'd like to try to build DECIPHER (and other bioconductor packages) into a condas package. Can anyone point me in a good direction to do something like this? Or if you are really feeling awesome, ouline the steps one would take?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here's how I managed to solve this:

I used conda skeleton files from another r-build as a template. It turns out, that for bioconductor packages [here's an example](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DECIPHER.html), there is a link to the git repository under the heading *Source Repository*.

I found the following guide helpful [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html).

I ended up making a meta.yaml file that looks like this

> ```
>  package:
>   name: r-decipher
>   version: "2.6.0"
>
> source:
>   git_url: https://git.bioconductor.org/packages/DECIPHER
>
> requirements:
>   build:
>     - r
>     - bioconductor-biostrings
>     - r-rsqlite
>
>   run:
>     - r
>     - bioconductor-biostrings
>     - r-rsqlite
> test:
> test:
>   commands:
>     # You can put additional test commands to be run here.
>     - $R -e "library('DECIPHER')"           # [not win]
>     - "\"%R%\" -e \"library('DECIPHER')\""  # [win]
>
> about:
>   home: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DECIPHER.html
> ```

I also made a build.sh file that looks like the following:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> if [[ $target_platform =~ linux.* ]] || [[ $target_platform == win-32 ]] || [[ $target_platform == win-64 ]] || [[ $target_platform
> ```
>
> == osx-64 ]]; then
>         export DISABLE_AUTOBREW=1
>         mv DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION.old
>         grep -v '^Priority: ' DESCRIPTION.old > DESCRIPTION
>         $R CMD INSTALL --build .
>       else
>         mkdir -p $PREFIX/lib/R/library/decipher
>         mv * $PREFIX/lib/R/library/decipher
>       fi

And a `bld.bat` that looks like the following

> ```
> "%R%" CMD INSTALL --build .
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 exit 1
> ```

All of these went in a source directory called r-decipher.

From the directory outside of that one I ran `conda build`, which worked (I may have had to install some dependencies, but it complains about them on the command line and each is available in CRAN at least) and then ran `conda install r-decipher`.

If anyone wants to use my specific build of r-decipher, it can now be found at https://anaconda.org/cramjaco/r-decipher

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate getting this to work on other systems, nor to use my online build.