# Cannot install R packages in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run R code in Jupyter and the R Kernel was added. Most of the time, packages can be installed successfully. However, some of the packages, such as `RCurl` and `ggmap`, would got error while installing.

**Example:**

```
install.packages("RCurl")
```

> Warning message in install.packages("RCurl"):
>   “installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
>
> Making 'packages.html' ... done

What should I do?

Comment: I have the same problem just with "ggmap"

Answer (score 18):

Try to specify CRAN as repository in your `install.packages` statement when installing `RCurl` and `ggmap`. For example:

```
install.packages("RCurl", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

This Stack Overflow post on [installing R packages through Anaconda/Jupyter beyond those included in R essential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705917/conda-how-to-install-r-packages-that-are-not-available-in-r-essentials) provides more detail.

(Side note: I had encountered the same issue when trying to install R packages on computer clusters. This solution worked for me.)

Comment: It seems as though you can run this line directly from a Jupyter NB. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

use conda comment:

`conda install r-RCurl`

Answer (score 2):

I kept getting the non-zero exit status when trying to install packages with Jupyter notebook with R kernel and was failing because of multiple dependencies when wanting to install a package. I am not an expert in any of these so please forgive me if I make an error in explaining or if it is a non-issue for you but please feel free to comment to clear things out. I just want to share my success story so hopefully it can help someone else: I am working on a MacBook Pro. Here are the information I get when I run R.version() on my jupyter notebook with R kernel:

```
$platform           'x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu'
$arch               'x86_64'
$os                 'linux-gnu'
$system             'x86_64, linux-gnu'
$language           'R'
$version.string     'R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)'
```

These are the steps to take to fix the issue:

1. Go to https://anaconda.org/
2. Search the package name that you are trying to install
   Copy the one line that is given to install the package, it should be something like:

   `Conda install -c r r-caret #conda install -c r r-package_name`

NOTE: sometimes during installing packages, you’re asked whether or not you want to continue, so add --y at the end of the above statement to continue, so something like this

```
Conda install -c r r-caret --y
```

(I will always add it just to be on the safe side)

3. Click on the new launcher (+ icon) to create a new notebook with PySpark (once opened it has .ipynp extension)
4. On the first cell paste the copied line from step 2 and run
5. Once done, restart the kernel on the current notebook
6. Restart the kernel on your other notebook with R kernel
7. Run library(package_name) on your notebook with R kernel (e.x. library(caret))

Answer (score 0):

`install.packages("Hmisc", .libPaths(), repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')`

This command will install the packagae in the conda
`"/home/user/anaconda3/lib/R/library"` and use the cran r repository as source.

**Add path in Anaconda**
As per [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15170774/12818901)
one can also add additional paths in anaconda to load libraries from (for eg., the location where R studio saves the user-installed packages) with
`.libPaths( c( .libPaths(), "~/userLibrary") )`

For example, the following worked for me:
In Anaconda :
`.libPaths( c( .libPaths(), "C:\Users\name\Documents\R\win-library\3.5") )`

When I tried to add anaconda's library path to RStudio, it resulted in errors (The procedure entry point MARK_NOT_MUTABLE could not be located in the dynamic link library << arose 4 times in succession) after installation of a package, though the package seemed to load.

*Replace **name** with your local user folder name*

**Add/change path in RStudio**
A useful link to make changes in default user-installed library paths :
https://www.accelebrate.com/library/how-to-articles/r-rstudio-library

**To find out where a package has been installed:**
`find.package('package_name')`

Answer (score 0):

The directions nobody else supplied worked for me, but I found this guide, and it worked. Spent way too much time trying all these when I just needed a few simple commands. https://developers.refinitiv.com/en/article-catalog/article/setup-jupyter-notebook-r

I already had R and python installed, so I skipped to step 3. The only seems to mention windows, but it worked for me on mac as well. After following them I was able to install the packages using `install.packages("dplyr", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")` in a cell in jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a directory in which your package will be and do for eg:

**install.packages('ggplot2',loc='your directory')**

Answer (score 0):

**First Step:** You can install the IRkernel packages by running the following command in an R console:`install.packages('IRkernel')`

**Second Step:** You will have to make Jupyter see the newly installed R kernel by installing a kernel spec. To install system-wide, set user to False in the installspec command `IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)`
[Setup Jupyter Notebook for R](https://developers.refinitiv.com/en/article-catalog/article/setup-jupyter-notebook-r)