# Installing packages in IRkernel on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, package, jupyter-irkernel

For the record, I have read the following threads and articles:

- [Conda for Data Science](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/conda-data-science/)
- [How to install R packages that are not available in “R-essentials”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705917/conda-how-to-install-r-packages-that-are-not-available-in-r-essentials)
- [Cannot install R packages in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459423/cannot-install-r-packages-in-jupyter-notebook)

However, if I use typical R approach:

```
.libPaths()
# '/home/ytu/anaconda3/lib/R/library'
install.packages("RPostgreSQL", lib = .libPaths(), repo = "https://cloud.r-project.org/")
```

It gives me:

> Warning message in install.packages("RPostgreSQL", lib = .libPaths(), repo = "https://cloud.r-project.org/"):
>     “installation of package ‘RPostgreSQL’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
>     Making 'packages.html' ... done

I Googled for a while but cannot get around with this problem. I specified *both* library path and CRAN mirror link, but it still doesn't work for me.

If I follow instructions of conda approach from the webpage, Tracebacks just flush my terminal at the step of `conda build r-rpostgresql`:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/ytu/anaconda3/bin/conda-build", line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(main())
>     File "/home/ytu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 413, in main
>       execute(sys.argv[1:])
>     File "/home/ytu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 404, in execute
>       verify=args.verify)
>     File "/home/ytu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda_build/api.py", line 193, in build
>       need_source_download=need_source_download, config=config, variants=variants)
>     File "/home/ytu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 1944, in build_tree
>       notest=notest,
>     File "/home/ytu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 1240, in build
>       utils.check_call_env(cmd, env=env, cwd=src_dir)
>     File "/home/ytu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 678, in check_call_env
>       return _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ(subprocess.check_call, *popenargs, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/ytu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 674, in _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ
>       return func(_args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/ytu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
>       raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
>   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/bin/bash', '-e', '/home/ytu/anaconda3/conda-bld/r-rpostgresql_1519543361442/work/conda_build.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

OS information by `uname -mrs`:

> Linux 3.13.0-105-generic x86_64

Comment: Submitted comment on Conda issue [Recent conda changes breaking Travis #6030](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6030#issuecomment-368290448).

Comment: Does this affect any R package, or is it something specific about RPostgresql? Try installing some really simple package to see if that works.

Comment: @ThomasK all R packages would fail. I tried packages like "r-lme4" but it showed the same error at `conda build r-lme4`. I can install R packages only from built ones which are already on conda R channel, but I cannot build my own.