# error in R jupyter tm package

Tags: r

I am getting an error in loading `tm` package even after installing the `nlp` package. I am trying this in R jupyter notebook however it is running fine in R studio.

```
install.packages("tm")

Installing package into 'C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.4'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
package 'tm' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning message:
"cannot remove prior installation of package 'tm'"

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpoLlSU1\downloaded_packages

library(tm)

Error in library(tm): there is no package called 'tm'
Traceback:

1. library(tm)
2. stop(txt, domain = NA)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459423/cannot-install-r-packages-in-jupyter-notebook?

Comment: Look at each directory in `.libPaths()` for a "tm" sub-directory, which (when found) will likely be an incomplete or failed installation. Move or remove that `tm` subdir and re-attempt installation.