# Warning message while installing R package on JupiterLab: "non_zero exit status"

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, installation, jupyter-lab

I am trying to write a R code on an JupyterLab file (.ipynb) with R kernel.

I am trying to load the library "reticulate" but first I need to install the package
the problem is that when I run:

```
install.packages("reticulate")
```

I get this message:

```
Warning message in install.packages("reticulate"):
“installation of package ‘reticulate’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

I found this link [khttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459423/cannot-install-r-packages-in-jupyter-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459423/cannot-install-r-packages-in-jupyter-notebook)
and I used the code suggested there

```
install.packages("reticulate", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

but I still get the same message

```
Warning message in install.packages("reticulate", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"): “installation of package ‘reticulate’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library' Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

**My question is: how can I install this package?**

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, the problem is that I first ran

```
install.packages("reticulate")
```

that didn't worked but created a folder or something that made impossible for

```
install.packages("reticulate", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

to work correctly, so I needed to cancel that folder first
now it works

Comment: How did you cancel the folder?