# aws sagemaker: install new r packages error

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to use jupyter notebook in AWS sagemaker with an `r` kernel. However there is a specific library that I want to use (`imager`) that does not exist. Based on previous SO [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42459747/1652217), I tried to do

```
install.packages("imager", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

This throws the following warning

```
Warning message in install.packages("imager", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"):
“installation of package ‘imager’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

However when I try to load this package again,

```
library("imager")
```

it throws the following error,

```
Error in library("imager"): there is no package called ‘imager’
Traceback:

1. library("imager")
```

I'm not sure why the aws sagemaker is not being able to locate the installed package for loading

Comment: Did you try to reconnect to the Kernel?

Comment: Yes but that doesnt seem to solve the problem

Comment: The warning means the package installation failed. Have you tried installing this outside SageMaker Notebook to isolate if the problem is with R environment on SageMaker Notebook or with the library installation?