# Can't install packages in Jupyter Lab R kernel

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyter-irkernel

I have tried to install basic packages in R using the R Jupyter lab kernel, but got this error message:

```
install.packages("devtools", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

> also installing the dependencies ‘credentials’, ‘curl’, ‘gert’, ‘gh’,
> ‘httr’, ‘ragg’, ‘usethis’, ‘pkgdown’, ‘rcmdcheck’, ‘rversions’,
> ‘urlchecker’
> Warning message in install.packages("devtools", repos =
> "http://cran.us.r-project.org"): “installation of package ‘curl’ had
> non-zero exit status” Warning message in install.packages("devtools",
> repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"): “installation of package
> ‘ragg’ had non-zero exit status” Warning message in
> install.packages("devtools", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"):
> “installation of package ‘credentials’ had non-zero exit status”
> Warning message in install.packages("devtools", repos =
> "http://cran.us.r-project.org"): “installation of package ‘httr’ had
> non-zero exit status” Warning message in install.packages("devtools",
> repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"): “installation of package
> ‘rcmdcheck’ had non-zero exit status” Warning message in
> install.packages("devtools", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"):
> “installation of package ‘rversions’ had non-zero exit status” Warning
> message in install.packages("devtools", repos =
> "http://cran.us.r-project.org"): “installation of package ‘urlchecker’
> had non-zero exit status” Warning message in
> install.packages("devtools", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"):
> “installation of package ‘gert’ had non-zero exit status” Warning
> message in install.packages("devtools", repos =
> "http://cran.us.r-project.org"): “installation of package ‘gh’ had
> non-zero exit status” Warning message in install.packages("devtools",
> repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"): “installation of package
> ‘pkgdown’ had non-zero exit status” Warning message in
> install.packages("devtools", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"):
> “installation of package ‘usethis’ had non-zero exit status” Warning
> message in install.packages("devtools", repos =
> "http://cran.us.r-project.org"): “installation of package ‘devtools’
> had non-zero exit status” Updating HTML index of packages in
> '.Library'
>
> Making 'packages.html' ...  done

I have tried to solve this problem using the following code:
[Cannot install R packages in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459423/cannot-install-r-packages-in-jupyter-notebook)

```
install.packages('IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)
```

But it does not work. Any idea to fix this problem?
Do you work with Jupyter lab with R kernel? Did you have this issue?

Comment: I'm not following what you are talking about solving with `install.packages('IRkernel')` and the line below that in the code block. Is R working already in your JupyterLab? If so, then I don't think that is the issue as Jupyter already sees the kernel and is using it. That solution got no votes there. A lot of other ones got votes and should be better to try. I thought the advice was to look into libPaths and then point Jupyter at that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705917/how-to-install-r-packages-that-are-not-available-in-r-essentials#comment82305250_35023854 ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have checked the paths with libPaths, and it is  '/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/R/library'. I have added the other libraries path used by Rstudio and Jupyter lab can load them now. I can't still install packages on Jupyter lab, but I do it on Rstudio, and use them on Jupyter lab. It's a bit clunky, but it is working.

Comment: Interesting. Defnitely clunky but glad it works. I think that was what [this answerer had also found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39649154/8508004).