# How to install Hotelling (R package) with conda?

Tags: r, conda

I am trying to install this package to use with R in conda:

[Hotelling](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hotelling/index.html)

However, I get this error message with the conda install:

$ conda install Hotelling
Fetching package metadata .................

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

- hotelling

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/r/osx-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/r/noarch

Comment: "hotelling" or "Hotelling"?

Comment: Neither work.  I think I need to specify another source, but what source should I specify?  Is that just a URL to the hotelling package?  How do I do that with conda? conda docs are unclear.

Comment: did you try `conda install -c r r-Hotelling`? Are you using jupyter, you can just install it from there

Comment: Just tried that command, but no luck.

Comment: what about the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705917/conda-how-to-install-r-packages-that-are-not-available-in-r-essentials)

Answer (score 2):

It isn't available on any anaconda repos. You can add it to a private repo and then install it using conda. Start an [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/) account and ensure you root-environment's conda/python is up to date (`conda update conda && conda update python`)

In some directory and in your root environment, use

`conda skeleton cran Hotelling`

That will make a skeleton for building the package based on the CRAN release.
Then build that (note the anaconda package is all lower-case despite the CRAN name being Title case):

`conda build --R=<whatever_your_version_of_r_is> r-hotelling`

Hopefully that will build. If it's succesful it should give you a message that tells you how to upload to your account on anaconda-cloud

`anaconda upload <path_to_your_built_r-hotelling> -u <your_account_name>`

Then install it:

`conda install -c <your_account_name> r-hotelling`

Comment: If it's of use, I uploaded `eulerr` to anaconda this morning, and my notes for getting it built are here: http://biolearnr.blogspot.co.uk/2018/01/pushing-r-eulerr-onto-anaconda-using.html