# Using R within conda next to R installation?

Tags: python, r, anaconda, conda

I just installed the anaconda environment to use Python. Now, within Python, I would like to make use of the rpy2 package. When running

```
conda install rpy2
```

conda suggests to install R along with some base packages. I suppose this will install R into the anaconda-environment.

Is there any danger of breaking my "normal" R installation by doing this, or can they co-exist, or is there anything I need to pay attention to?

How do I install specific R packages within the anaconda installation? Can I just follow [this answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705917/conda-how-to-install-r-packages-that-are-not-available-in-r-essentials)

All this is in Ubuntu 16.04 if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can install R and rpy2 from the Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: What woudl be the advantage of using the navigator, won't this have the same effects as installing it using conda and the default settings?

Comment: You're right. However, when you install RStudio from the navigator, it automatically installs all the required packages. I found it much easier to install it from there, hence the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: The conda support for R is not very good. You can find some R versions and packages from the official channels, and you may find some via conda-forge. You can find rpy2 via conda-forge, but not with version mathching R 4.x.x

What I do is:

1. install R via conda(-forge)
2. install pip via conda
3. install R packages of choice via R itself using `install.packages` in R.

This works so-so. I have no problems with it on my windows machine, where I have no global R installation, but I have some trouble on my Linux server where there is a global R.

... but it is the best suggestion I have.