# Jupyter Notebook: Installing R packages

Tags: r, ubuntu, package, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have seen this question asked various times in stackoverflow, e.g the following:

[error with install R packages on jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272451/error-with-install-r-packages-on-jupyter-notebook)

[Error with install packages R on jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286341/error-with-install-packages-r-on-jupyter-notebook)

[Install on jupyter notebook packages R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309755/install-on-jupyter-notebook-packages-r)

and

[conda - How to install R packages that are not available in "R-essentials"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705917/conda-how-to-install-r-packages-that-are-not-available-in-r-essentials)

However, the solutions offered haven't been working for me. I have tried to install the `ROCR` package in jupyter notebook and I get the following error:

[image]

Following the advice from [this](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/conda-data-science/) guide, I tried to replicate the example by installing the `LDAvis` package. First using `conda` in the ubuntu terminal as such:

```
conda skeleton cran ldavis
```

then

```
conda build r-ldavis/
```

However after doing this the package package doesn't install in jupyter, giving this instead:

I have also tried opening an R session in the terminal and installing the package there, however this doesn't help.

So in general how can I install R packages that aren't part of r-essentials, e.g. `ROCR` `LDAvis`? Probably I'm missing something very basic here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This could be because you have a different R installation and the package gets installed there. Have you tried adding something like `.libPaths("path/to/regular/R/libraries")` at the start of the notebook?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @ Sraffra,
I have tried this on my JN but still have the same error. I have also looked to be sure that the pacakge is installed, and it is. The issue I have is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59212970/installed-package-on-anaconda-not-accessible-in-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 1):

try to install using a terminal instead of Jupyter environment:

```
conda install r-ldavis
```

or

```
conda install r-rocr
```

Then restart Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

The directions nobody else supplied worked for me on any other thread, but I found this guide, and it worked. https://developers.refinitiv.com/en/article-catalog/article/setup-jupyter-notebook-r

I already had R and python installed, so I skipped to step 3. The only seems to mention windows, but it worked for me on mac as well. After following them I was able to install the packages using `install.packages("dplyr", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")` in a cell in jupyter.