# Install "imputeTS" through Anaconda to be used in Python

Tags: python, r, anaconda, conda, imputets

I'm trying to use "imputeTS" in my Python code and have installed rpy2 through Anaconda. (I don't have R on my laptop). But rpy2 doesn't seem to have the package "imputeTS" (Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'imputeTS'). I also tried using "conda install -c r r-imputeTS" and it still gave me the package not found error. Just wondering if there is a way to install "imputeTS" package through Anaconda to be used in Python? Thanks!

Comment: Downloaded R cos wasn't able to find a solution

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705917/conda-how-to-install-r-packages-that-are-not-available-in-r-essentials

Comment: I am actually one of the maintainers of the imputeTS package - but can't help much here, seems to be a anaconda/conda related issue. It seems like 'conda install' only works if  the package is added to their supported packages list. Looking at this list I have no idea, how it is composed. I don't really see a pattern - maybe I can just add imputeTS...but unfortunately I was not able to find out how I would do this.  If somebody knows more about this I'd be happy to know.

Comment: @stats0007 You might be able to add your library to [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org).

Comment: @AMC that's a great idea.