# Can't install any R package with jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I get this error whenever I try to install any package with jupyter notebook

```
  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
Rcpp  1.0.6  1.0.8              TRUE

installing the source package 'Rcpp'

Warning message in install.packages("Rcpp"):
"installation of package 'Rcpp' had non-zero exit status"
```

For this specific package, I was able to install it with `conda install` but some packages like `lifecontingencies` doesen't work and I get this message with `install.packages('lifecontingencies')`

```
also installing the dependencies 'Rcpp', 'markovchain'


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
                   binary source needs_compilation
Rcpp                1.0.6  1.0.8              TRUE
markovchain       0.8.5-4  0.8.6              TRUE
lifecontingencies   1.3.7  1.3.8              TRUE

installing the source packages 'Rcpp', 'markovchain', 'lifecontingencies'

Warning message in install.packages("lifecontingencies"):
"installation of package 'Rcpp' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("lifecontingencies"):
"installation of package 'markovchain' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("lifecontingencies"):
"installation of package 'lifecontingencies' had non-zero exit status"
```

And I get this with Conda

[image]

Is there a way to fix the `install.packages` command in jupyter notebook ?
My R version is 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CRAN package `lifedependencies` is now available through Conda Forge.<sup>**1**</sup> I generally recommend that all Conda R environments should source packages from Conda, otherwise one is likely to encounter compilation (really, library linking) issues.

```
conda install -c conda-forge r-lifedependencies
```

However, note that this is only available for R 4.0 and 4.1 at this time. If an R 3.6 version truly is required, then please request it by [filing an Issue on the feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/r-lifecontingencies-feedstock/issues).

For future reference, there are some details on adding CRAN packages to Conda Forge in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69921221/570918).

---

<sub>**[1]:** Note that R packages are typically prefixed with `r-` in the Conda ecosystem.</sub>