# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’

Tags: r, package, conda, xlsx, anaconda3

When I try to install the package xlsx I have the following error.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/gallo/asn/.conda/envs/scRNAseq/lib/R/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback:

1. library(xlsx)
2. tryCatch({
 .     attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
 .     ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 .     env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only)
 . }, error = function(e) {
 .     P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
 .         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
 .     else ""
 .     msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
 .         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
 .     if (logical.return && !quietly) 
 .         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
 .     else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
 . })
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. value[[3L]](cond)
6. stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)`
```

After Check Java Path in R, I try to reinstall rJava and then I check dynamic Library Path:

```
system("java -version")

Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "/home/gallo/asn/.conda/envs/scRNAseq/lib/R/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so")

install.packages("rJava", type = "source")

Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH "/home/gallo/asn/.conda/envs/scRNAseq/lib/R/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so")

library(xlsx)
```

--> RETURN SAME PROBLEM

Comment: (1) Make sure you have `openjdk-#-jre-headless` (where `#` is the version number you need) installed in the base OS (not in R); (2) your second `Sys.setenv` is missing an `=`, it should have a parsing error.

Comment: Can you load rJava itself with `library(rJava)`?

Comment: Conda R users should not use `install.packages()`, but rather stick to Conda Forge. Also PATH should never need to be manually manipulated. Everything Conda needs it will provide. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69921221/570918

Comment: Also, Conda Forge is the most reliable source for R packages and for that reason Mambaforge base is what I recommend for new Conda installations (not Anaconda).

Comment: @Dubukay When I load rJava appear this error: 
`library(rJava)
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rJava':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/gallo/asn/.conda/envs/scRNAseq/lib/R/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Yeah, so it'll be a problem with your Java installation process particularly, not xlsx. You may find more help searching for rJava install problems than xlsx, and when you're able to load rJava then xlsx should work without any problems.