# Is there something like requirements.txt for R?

Tags: r, pip, install.packages, requirements.txt

In Python, you can have a file `requirements.txt` where you can store a list of packages used into a file, and whenever other people want to run your programs and need to install the dependencies, they can just do `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

I think this helps a lot when deploying R script into production. Is there also something like that for R? If there is no such functionality, how do I replicate it?

Comment: Cannot tell what you are asking (and I'm not one of hte downvoters yet). Deployment is usually done with a package. Could be what is in a package DESCRIPTION file or what is in your `.Rprofile` file.

Comment: try using `packrat`

Comment: @MrFlick functionality of requirements.txt is to store all the packages needed for a project in a file so that you can download them and avoid running the script and getting `Error in library(xxx) : there is no package called ‘xxx’`.

Comment: My attempt to reproduce something like requirements.txt for R: https://gist.github.com/cannin/6b8c68e7db19c4902459

Comment: I wonder whether the functionality of requirements.txt is offered in Python or `pip`? I think it's the latter.

Answer (score 12):

As per the comments, you might want to look at building a package, and including the requirements in the DESCRIPTION file. If you're talking about putting a .R script "into production", you can put a function at the start to make sure the packages required are installed. Here's something along those lines that I have in my own package, and I can call `pkgLoad( <list of packages> )` at the beginning of any script to make sure the packages are installed and loaded. I include a list of my favourite packages, such that a call of `pkgLoad()` installs and loads all my usual suspects:

```
pkgLoad <- function( packages = "favourites" ) {

    if( length( packages ) == 1L && packages == "favourites" ) {
        packages <- c( "data.table", "chron", "plyr", "dplyr", "shiny",
                       "shinyjs", "parallel", "devtools", "doMC", "utils",
                       "stats", "microbenchmark", "ggplot2", "readxl",
                       "feather", "googlesheets", "readr", "DT", "knitr",
                       "rmarkdown", "Rcpp"
        )
    }

    packagecheck <- match( packages, utils::installed.packages()[,1] )

    packagestoinstall <- packages[ is.na( packagecheck ) ]

    if( length( packagestoinstall ) > 0L ) {
        utils::install.packages( packagestoinstall,
                             repos = "http://cran.csiro.au"
        )
    } else {
        print( "All requested packages already installed" )
    }

    for( package in packages ) {
        suppressPackageStartupMessages(
            library( package, character.only = TRUE, quietly = TRUE )
        )
    }

}
```

Note I've built my favourite CRAN mirror into the function, so make sure you edit that for your own needs.

Comment: In typical American fashion, I confused the domain extension of Australia for Austria, and wondered why you weren't downloading from the nearest mirror, especially since it is CRAN's central mirror.

Comment: `install.packages` should probably be substituted by `devtools::install_version`, because through requirements.txt one can not only install the necessary packages but also specific versions of them.