# How to install project dependencies in R?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

At work I received an old shiny application bundle. In there there is both a `manifest.json` file. Coming from python, the file looks like it could rebuild the original dependecies. The question is, how do install it in my current setup? I would like to have the equivalent of a `poetry install` or `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there something like requirements.txt for R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928326/is-there-something-like-requirements-txt-for-r), See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54534153/install-r-packages-from-requirements-txt-file, and https://github.com/rstudio/packrat. The manifest is very likely coming from `pakrat`. Please refer to their document how to install from the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment, I made my own solution that worked well.

First create a `requirements.txt` with a python script.

```py
"""
Read a manifest.json and output a requirements.txt file
"""
import json

file = 'manifest.json'
out = 'requirements.txt'

with open(file) as json_file:
  data = json.load(json_file)

with open(out, 'w') as f:
  for pkg_name in data['packages'].keys():
      pkg_version = data['packages'][pkg_name]['description']['Version']
      res = f'{pkg_name} {pkg_version} \n'
      f.write(res)
```

Then install all the old dependencies with this `bash` script

```sh
while IFS=" " read -r package version; 
do
   Rscript -e "devtools::install_version('"$package"', version='"$version"')"; 
done < "requirements.txt"
```