# Maintain different versions of R package for open source contribution

Tags: r, virtualenv, conda

[Packrat is often recommended as the virtual environment for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283171/virtual-environment-in-r), but it doesn't fully meet my need of contributing to R open source. Packrat's "virtual environment" is stored directly in the project directory, requiring me to modify the `.gitignore` to ignore them when I make a pull request to the open source upstream.

In contrast, something like `conda` stores the virtual environment somewhere else, leaving no trace in the project codebase itself.

So how do R open source contributors deal manage dependencies during package development? Ideally the solution would work well with `devtools` and Rstudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is nothing wrong in having Packrat in `.gitignore`.
2. You can use [`.git/info/exclude`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_description) file thus avoiding touching the `.gitignore`.

Comment: `.git/info/exclude` seems like the solution! On the point of having Packrat in `.gitignore`, isn't it a problem if the package maintainer doesn't use Packrat and thus doesn't want to include it? I can modify `.gitignore`, but the package maintainer wouldn't like the change. Or perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: That's a question of policy and communication. For example, I use `vim` and never used Emacs, and my `vim` is configured to not store backup files but I still have `*.bak` and `*~` in `.gitignore` files in different projects ([1](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/6e17054a2ee004bcaeee7e915d31dd9270f7694c/.gitignore), [2](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/blob/24475a148b303da781ced12105f231e5c0579981/.gitignore)) because that helps other developers who have different configuration.