# Install R packages from requirements.txt file

Tags: r, pip, install.packages, requirements.txt

Is there a functionality like requirements.txt in Python, where you can store a list of packages used into a file, and whenever other people want to run your programs and need to install the dependencies, they can just do pip install -r requirements.txt.

I think, this helps a lot when deploying R script into production. If there is no such functionality, how do I replicate it?

Answer (score 5):

Create a requirements file with any delimiter between packages and its version version.
For eg.

```
data.table 1.11.4
DBI 1.0.0
curl 3.2
```

And then install it by parsing the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while IFS=" " read -r package version; 
do 
  Rscript -e "devtools::install_version('"$package"', version='"$version"')"; 
done < "requirements.txt"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `packrat` with your project. [link](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/)

Answer (score 0):

Better late then never.

There is also `renv` (https://github.com/rstudio/renv) which to my understanding is similar to `packrat` (https://github.com/rstudio/packrat).
The differences between both are highligted at https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/packrat.html.

See the getting started guide for a good overview https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html.

There is also this related post [Virtual environment in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283171/virtual-environment-in-r).